# Difference Between Variable And Textvariable in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, ttk

My code:

```py
my_var = tk.StringVar()

m_var2 = tk.StringVar()

my_entry1 = ttk.Entry(root, width=16, textvariable=my_var)

my_radio1 = ttk.Radiobutton(root, text="1", variable=my_var2)
```

Now what is the difference between `textvariable` and `variable` ?

Comment: Each type of widget defines its own set of options that can be specified; there's no reason to expect them to be the same for all widgets.  Actually, Radiobuttons do have a `textvariable=` option (in addition to the `variable=` option that you're already using): it's an alternative to the `text=` option, that sets (and automatically updates) the button's label according to a Var's conteents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`variable` and `textvariable` are similar in concept, in that both represent variable data.

In the case of `textvariable`, which is mostly used with `Entry` and `Label` widgets, it is a variable that will be displayed as text. When the variable changes, the text of the widget changes as well.

In the case of `variable`, which is mostly used for `Checkbutton` and `Radiobutton` widgets, it represents the value that the widget holds. For example, you may have radio buttons with the text "Yes" and "No", but the actual values may be 1 and 0. In this case the `variable` represents the value of the widget.

Answer (score 0):

In Tkinter, a `variable` and a `textvariable` are both types of variable data. A `textvariable` is a variable that is displayed as text. When the variable changes, the text of the widget changes as well.

A text variable is a type of variable that represents an unknown text value. For example, if you want to ask a template user for their first name, you would create a Text variable in your template to capture that specific item of data.

A `variable` defined using `StringVar()` holds a string data where you can set text value and can retrieve it. You can pass this variable to `textvariable` parameter for a widget like `Entry`. The widget will automatically get updated with the new value whenever the value of the `StringVar()` variable changes.